# Livewire V3 Call to undefined function Livewire\Concerns\data_forget()

Tags: laravel-livewire, undefined-function

Please, I need help about this
I use Laravel 10, Livewire version 3,
when run in WSL2 at localhost, this code have no problem.

but if run in a production at linux serve ubuntu, i have this error:
Call to undefined function Livewire\Concerns\data_forget()
in this line:

```
   $this->reset('openModalAsign','usersWithRoles','user_id','rolId');
```

I tried clear cache, but the error persist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the error!
in Livewire V3 the $this->reset command only works if you declare its properties public at the beginning.

This is because the reset() command assigns these values.

**Before**

```
class Roles extends Component
{
   public openModalAsign;
   public usersWithRoles;
   public user_id;
   public rolId;
   ...
}
```

**After**

```
class Roles extends Component
{
   public openModalAsign = [];
   public usersWithRoles = [];
   public user_id = null;
   public rolId = null;
   ...
}
```